# Book about a teenage witch, teal green cover with a ghostly circle

Tags: story-identification

This is a fantasy book in the sense that a modern day girl/teenage girl is a witch – and that's basically all I remember of the plot.

The cover was simple – a teal green background with a ghostly circle in the center of it, all wispy and stuff. I remember it being something like *Ghostball*, but I've searched that over and under, so that's wrong.

The series is meant for young adults and it MIGHT part of a series.

Comment: When did you read it / see it?

Comment: How do you know that she's a witch if she's "modern day"? Does she learn to do magic or is she born with it? You say it might be "young adult", were there any love interests?

Comment: The Secret Circle books by L. J. Smith? The titles are circled, and the third book has a greenish cover. https://www.fantasticfiction.com/s/lisa-jane-smith/secret-circle/

Answer (score 2):

While it is a long shot, the series *[Spooksville](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spooksville)* may be what you are looking for, especially if you don't really remember many of the details.

Many of the covers match (Most are wispy, quite a few are green. A few have actual circles, but most are "circled" in the center of the books.)

Sample covers shown below:

[image][image]

There is a witch as a recurring character in the town, but one of the main characters is named "Watch".

Answer (score 1):

Could it be the *[Doomspell](https://www.goodreads.com/series/61055-doomspell)* trilogy by Cliff McNish?

> In a blaze of light, rush of wind and scrabble of claws, Rachel and
> Eric are ripped through the wall and hurtled on to another world. Like
> thousands of other children before them, they have been snatched away
> by the Witch.
>
> But this time the Witch has met her match. Rachel discovers that she
> has extraordinary gifts: she can transform herself into a feather, or
> fly on an owl’s back, just as the Witch can. The Witch is excited she
> has found someone to use for her own evil purposes. But for the
> Witch’s victims, Rachel is their only hope.

[image]

Comment: If so, it will be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/172087/fantasy-book-with-young-female-protagonist-magic-matter-manipulation-tasteles