# Children's fantasy book that involved magic based in belief, and scarecrow style protectors

Tags: story-identification, magic, childrens-novel

I'm trying to identify this series I read around 15 years ago.

It was a fantasy trilogy, the first book had hints of Narnia to it, it started with a girl and her brother being sucked into another world through a portal in their basement (?) that generated alot of wind (the girl may have jumped in after the brother), and there was a mention of airplane models being thrown around. I think not long after she meets the Queen (or similar) of this world and her servant and the girl discovers she has abilities in this world such as being able to conjure a chocolate spread sandwich, however it tastes awful and when she creates it she has to visualise the taste as well. I'm sure the world had some sort of eternal winter deal as well. I can remember very little from this book other than I think the Queen wants the brother for something.

I can't remember much of the second other than the brother starts developing some sort of powers, and in the third book he becomes similar to a scarecrow, living on a platform structure being fed by harpy like women while he somehow keeps the world safe. I think there were other children helping with this.

This gets a bit confusing now as I was certain the second book had silver in the title and an orange background which fits exactly with "The Silver City" and some of the plot points do match, but not my strongest one which is the way magic worked in the first book (where she had to holistically conjure the whole object), there is a possibility these are two separate series!

Comment: Great first Question! Because it had the same answer as another one, it's been marked as a duplicate, but that's not a bad thing. For more details, have a look at the [help] then take our [tour]

Answer (score 4):

This is "The Doomspell Trilogy" as found by this answer [Fantasy book with young female protagonist, magic, matter manipulation, tasteless chocolate sandwiches and room with aquarium walls](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/172087/fantasy-book-with-young-female-protagonist-magic-matter-manipulation-tasteles?rq=1) . The silver city was by the same author, and had similar cover art, which is likely where the confusion came from (I may even have read that book thinking it was part of the trilogy).

Comment: Yes! Fantastic series (both Doomspell and Silver, really). Don't forget to mark your own answer as accepted when you can (I think the system will let you do that after 48 hours).