# Help identifying children's book with moon travel through magical vortex and spiders

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for a specific science fiction or fantasy book for children/teens that I read when I was younger. The plot involves a group of children (or just a girl ? or her brother too ?) who are drawn to the moon by a witch through a magical vortex (I think) in a cave. I remember that spiders played a significant role in the story as well. I've been trying to recall the title, but I haven't had any luck so far. Can anyone help me identify this book? Thank you!

Comment: Boy+girl+spiders+moon travel makes me think Philip Reeve's *Larklight*, but the witch doesn't fit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It was a basement, not a cave; but I think this is [the "Doomspell" trilogy by Cliff McNish](http://allreaders.com/book-review-summary/doomspell-24318). The boy is captured by a witch, and his sister follows to save him. The witches have spiders that clean their teeth.

Comment: What a fantastic series that was. Cliff McNish is a truly underappreciated gem of a writer (his Silver trilogy and *The Hunting Ground* were also memorably great).

Comment: If so, it's a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/172087/23243

Comment: Wow, thank you ! Even with the name I do not so easily find it in french, I guess it is not so popular, but I still have a a strong impression of my reading years ago (for cave and basement I forgot it was a false friend...)